# i want to send email with multiple database values

Tags: codeigniter

```
   if($records->result()>0) 
    {

        foreach ($records->result() as $user)
        {

            $username= ('first name='.$user->u_first_name.'<br/>'.'Last name='.$user->u_last_name.'<br/>'.'Email='.$user->u_email.'<br/>'.'Property Id='.$user->propertyid);
            $username.="<br/>";
            $username.="-------------------------";
            $username.="<br/>";



            $email_template =  file_get_contents($this->config->item('base_url').'assets/email/email.html');
            $email_template = str_replace("[[EMAIL_HEADING]]", $mail_content->subject, $email_template);
            $email_template = str_replace("[[EMAIL_CONTENT]]", $username, $email_template);
            $email_template = str_replace("[[SITEROOT]]", $this->config->item('base_url'), $email_template);
            $email_template = str_replace("[[LOGO]]",$this->config->item('base_url')."assets", $email_template);
            $this->email->message(html_entity_decode($email_template));      
            $this->email->send();
            print_r($email_template);
```

this is my code

Comment: well, what is the point of using framework if you dont gonna use its features ? like MVC

Comment: This is not a question! Please try to formulate a question at least.

Answer (score 2):

/* UPDATE */

You can use a view for your template like normal (passing in values), setting the third parameter as TRUE to return the html.

To send one email with all database records, just pass the entire result object into the view, the process it in the view using your standard foreach loops, etc..

E.g

```
if($records->result()>0) {
    $email_template = $this->load->view('email_template', array('heading' => 'My Email Report', 'records' => $records->result(), TRUE);
    $this->email->message($email_template);      
    $this->email->send();
    print_r($email_template);
}
```

Then the view (/view/email_template) would be something like;

```
<h1><?php echo $heading; ?>
<p> Records;</p>
<table>
<?php
foreach ($records as $r) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $r->u_first_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r->u_last_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r->u_email; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r->propertyid; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: actually my question is i want to send email to someone with multiple database record my code shows only one record and i want multiple

Comment: do you mean send someone with multiple records only or do you mean you want to have multiple records sent to one person?

Comment: yes want to send to one person but multiple records from database actually i want to send multiple users information through email

Comment: see revised answer, is this what you want?

Comment: i am not using view page i am using email_templet

Comment: Have updated answer again, don't understand the problem with using a view for the email template, the third parameter returns the html (or plain text if that's all you want), it doesn't process it.

Comment: ok no problem thanx Rooney...I will try it but I am sending email in a specific format